# Fast function to add vector elements by their names

Tags: performance, r, vector, rcpp

I wrote this `R` function that, given any number of vectors (`...`) combines them by summing the respective element values ​​based on their names.

```
add_vectors <- function(...) {
  a <- list(...)
  nms <- sort(unique(unlist(lapply(a, names))))
  out <- numeric(length(nms))
  names(out) <- nms
  for (v in a) out[names(v)] <- out[names(v)] + v

  out
}
```

Example:

```
v1 <- c(a=2,b=3,e=4)
v2 <- c(b=1,c=6,d=0,a=4)
add_vectors(v1, v2)
#
a b c d e 
6 4 6 0 4
```

I'm trying to write an equivalent function which is **much faster**.

Unfortunately at the moment I have no idea how to achieve this in `R` so I thought to `Rcpp`.
But, in order to convert in `Rcpp` this function I miss some concepts:

1. How to manage the `...` parameter. With a parameter of `List` type in `Rcpp` ?
2. How to iterate the vectors in the `...` parameter.
3. How to access (and then sum) the elements of the vectors by their name (this is very trivial in `R`, but I cannot figure how to do in `Rcpp`).

So I'm looking for someone that can help me to improve the performances of this function (in `R` or `Rcpp`, or both).

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: How big are your vectors? Isn't this fast enough? `tapply(c(v1, v2), factor(c(names(v1), names(v2)), levels=union(names(v1), names(v2))), sum)`

Comment: Or this: `unlist(lapply(split(c(v1,v2), names(c(v1,v2))), sum))`. Although I suspect the first one will be faster on huge vectors than using `split`.

Comment: @Arun: thanks for your solutions, I've done a benchmark on short vectors and your solutions are about 2-3 time slower (probably the result of huge vectors would reverse).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would use something like this:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp; 

// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericVector add_all(List vectors){
    RCPP_UNORDERED_MAP<std::string,double> out ; 
    int n = vectors.size() ;
    for( int i=0; i<n; i++){
        NumericVector x = vectors[i] ;
        CharacterVector names = x.attr("names") ;
        int m = x.size() ;

        for( int j=0; j<m; j++){
            String name = names[j] ;
            out[ name ] += x[j] ;   
        }
    }
    return wrap(out) ;
}
```

with the following wrapper:

```
add_vectors_cpp <- function(...){
    add_all( list(...) )
}
```

`RCPP_UNORDERED_MAP` being just a typedef to `unordered_map`, either in `std::` or in `std::tr1::` depending on your compiler, etc ...

The trick here is to create a regular list out of the `...` using the classic `list(...)`.

If you really wanted to pass down directly `...` in C++ and deal with it internally, you would have to use the [`.External`](http://help.r-enthusiasts.com/library/base/html/CallExternal.html) interface. This is very rarely use, so Rcpp attributes don't support the [`.External`](http://help.r-enthusiasts.com/library/base/html/CallExternal.html) interface.

With [`.External`](http://help.r-enthusiasts.com/library/base/html/CallExternal.html), it would look like this (untested):

```
SEXP add_vectors(SEXP args){
    RCPP_UNORDERED_MAP<std::string,double> out ; 
    args = CDR(args) ;
    while( args != R_NilValue ){
        NumericVector x = CAR(args) ;

        CharacterVector names = x.attr("names") ;
        int m = x.size() ;

        for( int j=0; j<m; j++){
            String name = names[j] ;
            out[ name ] += x[j] ;   
        }        
        args = CDR(args) ;
    }   
    return wrap(out) ;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for a cleaner (and more complete) solution @Romain Francois. Thanks also for the clarification about `...` parameter and `CDR` function.

Comment: Using `list(...)` will create a copy of all the inputs, which might be a heavy performance price to pay.  A more complicated approach (but doesn't need .External) is to pass the function environment and the unevaluated argument names.

Comment: Good catch. Maybe it would be worth to support the `.External` interface in the [`Rcpp::export`](http://help.r-enthusiasts.com/library/Rcpp/html/exportAttribute.html) attribute

Answer (score 3):

Compiling to bytecode using the **compiler** package gives you some improvement. This package ships with R.

```
library(compiler)
library(microbenchmark)

add_vectors_cmp <- cmpfun(add_vectors)

set.seed(1)
v <- rpois(length(letters), 10)
names(v) <- letters
vs <- replicate(150, v, simplify=FALSE)

not_compiled <- function(l) do.call(add_vectors, l)
compiled <- function(l) do.call(add_vectors_cmp, l)

plot(microbenchmark(not_compiled(vs), compiled(vs)))
```

[image]

Comment: I know `compiler` package and related but this is not what I'm looking for. Anyway, thanks! =)

Answer (score 3):

I just wrote a binary version (2 input) of this function in `Rcpp`.

I don't know how to use the `...` parameter (and how to iterate on it) in `Rcpp` so I've encapsulated this function in a simple `R` function.

### SOLUTION

```
library(Rcpp)
cppFunction(
  code = '
  NumericVector add_vectors_cpp(NumericVector v1, NumericVector v2) {
    // merging names, sorting them and removing duplicates
    std::vector<std::string> nms1 = v1.names();
    std::vector<std::string> nms2 = v2.names();
    std::vector<std::string> nms;
    nms.resize(nms1.size() + nms2.size());
    std::merge(nms1.begin(), nms1.end(), nms2.begin(), nms2.end(), nms.begin());
    std::sort(nms.begin(), nms.end());
    nms.erase(std::unique(nms.begin(), nms.end()), nms.end());
    // summing vector elements by their names and storing them in an associative data structure
    int num_names = nms.size();
    std::tr1::unordered_map<std::string, double> map(num_names);
    for (std::vector<int>::size_type i1 = 0; i1 != nms1.size(); i1++) {
        map[nms1[i1]] += v1[i1];
    }
    for (std::vector<int>::size_type i2 = 0; i2 != nms2.size(); i2++) {
        map[nms2[i2]] += v2[i2];
    }
    // extracting map values (to use as result vector) and keys (to use as result vector names)
    NumericVector vals(map.size());
    for (unsigned r = 0; r < num_names; ++r) {
        vals[r] = map[nms[r]];
    }
    vals.names() = nms;
    return vals;
  }',
  includes = '
  #include <vector>
  #include <tr1/unordered_map>
  #include <algorithm>'
)
```

Then the encapsulation in a `R` function:

```
add_vectors_2 <- function(...) {
  Reduce(function(x, y) add_vectors_cpp(x, y), list(...))
}
```

Note that this solution uses the `STL` libs.
I don't know if this is a *well written C++* solution or if a more efficient solution can be written (probably), but for sure it is a good (and working) starting point.

### EXAMPLES OF USE

```
v1 <- c(b = 1, d = 2, c = 3, a = 4, e = 6, f = 5)
v2 <- c(d = 2, c = 3, a = 4, e = 6, f = 5)
add_vectors(v1, v2, v1, v2)
#  a  b  c  d  e  f 
# 16  2 12  8 24 20
add_vectors_2(v1, v2, v1, v2)
#  a  b  c  d  e  f 
# 16  2 12  8 24 20
```

#### NOTE: this function works also for vector which names are not uniques.

```
v1 <- c(b = 1, d = 2, c = 3, a = 4, e = 6, f = 5)
v2 <- c(d = 2, c = 3, a = 4, e = 6, f = 5, f = 10, a = 12)
add_vectors(v1, v2)
#  a  b  c  d  e  f 
# 16  1  6  4 12 15 
add_vectors_2(v1, v2)
#  a  b  c  d  e  f 
# 20  1  6  4 12 20
```

As showed by the last example this solution works even when the input vectors have non-unique names, **summing the elements of the same vector with the same name**.

### BENCHMARKS

My solution is about 3 times faster than `R` solution in the simplest case (two vectors). It is good imporvement, but probably there is scope for further small improvements with a better `C++` solution.

```
Unit: microseconds
                 expr    min     lq median      uq     max neval
  add_vectors(v1, v2) 65.460 68.569 70.913 73.5205 614.274   100
add_vectors_2(v1, v2) 20.743 23.389 25.142 26.9920 337.544   100
```

[image]

When applying this function to more vectors the performances degrade a bit (only 2 time faster).

```
Unit: microseconds
                                 expr     min       lq  median       uq     max neval
  add_vectors(v1, v2, v1, v2, v1, v1) 105.994 195.7565 205.174 212.5745 993.756   100
add_vectors_2(v1, v2, v1, v2, v1, v1)  66.168 125.2110 135.060 139.7725 666.975   100
```

So the last goal now is to remove the `R` *wrapping* function managing the `...` (or similar, e.g. `List`) parameter directly with `Rcpp`.

I think that this is possible because `Rcpp` sugar have features similar to it (e.g. the *porting* of the `sapply` function), but would appreciate some feedback.

Answer (score 3):

The data.table package is excellent at performing aggregation and other operations. I'm not really an expert, but

```
library(data.table)
add_vectors5 <- function(...)
{
    vals <- do.call(c, list(...))
    dt <- data.table(nm=names(vals), v=vals, key="nm")
    dt <- dt[,sum(v), by=nm]
    setNames(dt[[2]], dt[[1]])
}
```

seems to be about 2x faster than other pure R implementations. A more cryptic implementation is

```
add_vectors6 <- function(..., method="radix")
{
    vals <- do.call(c, list(...))
    ## order by name, but use integers for faster order algo
    idx <- match(names(vals), unique(names(vals)))
    o <- sort.list(idx, method=method, na.last=NA)

    ## cummulative sum of ordered values
    csum <- cumsum(vals[o])

    ## subset where ordering factor changes, and then diff
    idxo <- idx[o]
    diff(c(0, csum[idxo != c(idxo[-1], TRUE)]))
}
```

which is prone to numeric overflow; use method="radix" if there are less than 100,000 names, as implied on `?sort.list`, otherwise method="quick".

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that you'll get much speedup.  I took an alternate approach in R code, combining all inputs into a single vector, then resplitting by name, and aggregating with `vapply`.  More or less all the functions there call internal C code, and the speed is comparable to your function for large vectors (tested on vectors of length 1e5 and 1e6).  It's a little slower for the toy examples of 3 or 4 elements.

```
add_vectors2 <- function(...) {
  y <- do.call(c, unname(list(...)))
  vapply(split(y, names(y)), sum, numeric(1))
}

#Longer sample vectors
m <- 1e3
n <- 1e6
v1 <- sample(m, n, replace = TRUE)
names(v1) <- sample(n)
v2 <- sample(m, n, replace = TRUE)
names(v2) <- sample(seq_len(n) + n / 2)  

#Timings
k <- 20
system.time(for(i in 1:k) add_vectors(v1, v2))   #5 or 6 seconds
system.time(for(i in 1:k) add_vectors2(v1, v2))  #same
```

EDIT: Vector names fixed to be unique, reflecting Roland's comment.  My solution is now a little slower than OP's.

Comment: The OP's function makes the assumption that names are unique for each vector, yours doesn't. Thus, results differ for your large vectors.

Comment: @Roland: the fact that the names must be unique is not a primary requirement, instead the speed it's. ;)